# Polar decomposition of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

**Prove : If $\nu$ is a complex-valued measure on a measurable space $(X,S)$, then there exists a non-negative real-valued measure $\mu$ on $S$, and a complex-valued measurable function $u$ on $X$ such that $|u(x)|=1$ for all $x \in X$, such that $\nu(E)$=$\int_{E}u(x)d\mu(x)$ for all $E \in S$**

Can anyone help me with this problem and guide me where to start?

Thanks.

Comment: You can imitate what you would do if you have to construct the same factorization, but for just a complex number $z$. You can take the absolute value, $|z|$, that would be real and non-negative. Then you can *divide* $z/|z|$ and show that that has absolute value $1$.

Comment: Perhaps the significant step would be the **divide** in the case of measures. But there is one named theorem that speaks of existence of a measurable function such that one measure is the integral of the function in the other measure.

Answer (score 2):

It is a theorem in Rudin's book (Real and complex analysis, p124, thm6.12), known as polar decomposition of measures and is a cosequence of Radon-Nikodym thm.

Comment: This should be better suited as a comment.